# how to read data from daughter files and append it to the end of parent file using linux

Tags: linux, sed, append, parent

I have 100 daughter files with the same extension
like

```
thin1.txt
thin2.txt
thin3.txt
. . .
. . .
. . .
```

Each file contains a number like

```
0.99456
```

I want to append all the numbers of these files to a single parent file.
I have to plot them later so I want to combine all of them.

I can read each file using

```
for (( j=1 ; j<101 ; j++ ))  
do
d="$(cat thin$j.txt)"   # reading the line for the file
echo $d >singleFile.txt # it over write each time  :(
done
```

I expect some sed command to do the rest after I am able to read the string from the file.

Any suggestions?

best regards,

Hamad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9.]\+$/w results.txt' thin*.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `>>` to append string to a file.

You also can try:

```
$ cat thin{1..101}.txt >singleFile.txt
```

Comment: i used it already but it append to the same line and not the next

Comment: Does your `thinXX.txt` contains newline in it?

Comment: Did you try to change `>` to `>>`.

Comment: thinxx.txt contains only 1 number . each file has a single number that has to be appended to the parent file , so that later I can use it in excel importation and graph plotting

Comment: @hamaskhan: In that case you can do it with a loop like `for f in thin{1..101}.txt ; do cat "$f" >> singleFile.txt ; printf '\n' >> singleFile.txt ; done`

Comment: @kev , it still appends on the same line and not 1 per line.

Comment: it works but it overwrites each time the new data is read from the next thin file and written to parent file.

Comment: @hamaskhan: If `singleFile.txt` is overwritten each time then you said `>` and not `>>`. Or, your `thin` files might begin with `\r`.

Comment: @Sorpigal  the problem is still that it appends on the same line . I want it to be 1 each per line.. not 100 on a single line without  a space

Comment: @hamaskhan: "Appends on the same line" != "overwrites" and in any case my comment above about looping and printing would fix that.